# Analytic Geometry (high school): Why is the sum of the distances from any point of the ellipse to the two foci the major axis?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I don't understand where that formula came from. Could someone explain? For example any point $(x,y)$ on the ellipse from the two foci $(-c,0)$ and $(c,0)$ is equal to $2a$ where $2a$ is the distance of the major axis. Where did this idea come from?

Comment: The ellipse is defined to be the curve for which the distance from a pair of points is constant.

Comment: http://www.maa.org/joma/volume8/kalman/ellipse4.html

Comment: But how do you know that the constant is 2a?

Comment: I totally understand the POV of the person who wrote the pdf thanks.

Answer (score 6):

As the center is the midpoint of the foci, so the center $O(0,0)$

As the foci lie on the major axis , so the equation of the major axis $y=0\implies$ the equation of the minor axis $x=0$

Now,  if the length of the major, minor axes be $2a,2b$ respectively with eccentricity $=e$

So, the equation of the ellipse is $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$

Any point $P$ on the ellipse can be $P(a\cos\theta,b\sin\theta)$

So, the distance between $(a\cos\theta,b\sin\theta), (ae,0)$  is

$\sqrt{(ae-a\cos\theta)^2+(b\sin\theta-0)^2}$
$=\sqrt{a^2e^2+a^2\cos^2\theta-2a^2e\cos\theta+a^2(1-e^2)(1-\cos^2\theta)}$
$=a(1-e\cos\theta)$ as $0\le e<1,-1\le \cos\theta\le 1$ and $b^2=a^2(1-e^2)$

Similarly,  the distance between $(a\cos\theta,b\sin\theta), (-ae,0)$  is $=a(1+e\cos\theta)$

Comment: I don't understand where got eccentricity "e" (?)

Comment: @Person, do you know the relationship among the lengths of major & minor axes and  eccentricity?

Answer (score 3):

The formula for an ellipse centred at the origin is $$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1 \tag{1} $$ where a>b.

Now let us define a constant (note at this point I'm just defining a constant - nothing about foci)
$$f = \sqrt{a^2 - b^2}\tag{2}$$
Let us now pick 2 points on the x axis (f,0) and (-f,0).

The distance from point (f,0) to a point on the ellipse is (by Pythagoras)
$$r_1 = \sqrt{(x-f)^2 + y^2}$$
and the distance from point (-f,0) to the same point on the ellipse is
$$r_2 = \sqrt{(x+f)^2 + y^2}$$
Looking at $r_1$ first
$$r_1 = \sqrt{(x-f)^2 + y^2}\tag{3}$$
From (1)
$$y^2 = (1-\frac{x^2}{a^2})b^2\tag{4}$$
so substituting (4) into (3) we have
$$r_1 = \sqrt{(x-f)^2 + (1-\frac{x^2}{a^2})b^2}$$
Expanding this out we get
$$r_1 = \sqrt{x^2 -2fx + f^2 + b^2 - \frac{x^2b^2}{a^2}}$$
Rearranging
$$r_1 = \sqrt{x^2(1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}) -2fx + f^2 + b^2}$$

$$ r_1 = \sqrt{x^2(\frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2}) -2fx + f^2 + b^2}$$

but from (2) $f^2 = a^2 - b^2$ so 
$$ r_1 = \sqrt{x^2(\frac{f^2}{a^2}) -2fx + f^2 + b^2}$$
also from (2) $f^2 + b^2 = a^2 $ so 
$$ r_1 = \sqrt{x^2(\frac{f^2}{a^2}) -2fx + a^2}$$
and rearrange under the sq root
$$r_1 = \sqrt{(a - \frac{xf}{a})^2}$$
$$r_1 = a - \frac{xf}{a}$$
Similarly you can show that 
$$r_2 = a + \frac{xf}{a}$$
so
$$r_1+r_2 = 2a$$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that the foci of the ellipse are $(c,0)$ and $(-c,0)$, and that the major axis runs from $(-x,0)$ to $(x,0)$. Then the length of the major axis is $2x$. At the same time, the distance from $(x,0)$ to $(c,0)$ is $(x-c)$, and the distance from $(x,0)$ to $(-c,0)$ is $x-(-c) = x+c$. Then the sum of these distances is

$$ (x-c) + (x+c) = 2x$$

So the sum of the distances is precisely equal to the length of the major axis.

Comment: Well, the OP's queztion is actually two-part: firstly, to prove that the sum is the same for any point and, secondly, that it is equal to 2a. Without proving the first part, your calculations do not really demonstrate much.

Answer (score 2):

OK, imagine you have tacks at the points $(-c,0$ and $(c,0)$, which hold each end of a string of length $2 a$.  We draw an ellipse by holding a pen taut against the string.  The sum of the distances to a point on the ellipse from each of the tack points is

$$\sqrt{(x+c)^2+y^2} + \sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2} = 2 a$$

The trick is to manage the algebra so that the derivation is readable.  First, square both sides to get

$$(x-c)^2 + (x+c)^2 + 2 y^2 + 2 \sqrt{x^2+y^2+c^2+2 c x} \sqrt{x^2+y^2+c^2-2 c x} = 4 a^2$$

This simplifies a little to

$$x^2+y^2+c^2+\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+c^2)^2-4 c^2 x^2} = 2 a^2$$

Now we need to rid ourselves of this remaining square root by isolating it:

$$\begin{align}(x^2+y^2+c^2)^2-4 c^2 x^2 &= [2 a^2 - (x^2+y^2+c^2)]^2\\ &= 4 a^4 - 4 a^2 (x^2+y^2+c^2) + (x^2+y^2+c^2)^2 \end{align}$$

We have some fortuitous cancellation which leaves us with a quadratic.  Rearrange to get

$$(a^2-c^2) x^2 + a^2 y^2 = a^2 (a^2-c^2)$$

or, in standard form:

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{a^2-c^2} = 1$$

Note that, for an ellipse, $a>c$.  We interpret $a$ to be the semimajor axis, $c$ to be the focal length, and $b=\sqrt{a^2-c^2}$ is the semiminor axis.

Comment: My issue with your presentation is that you started out saying that d1 + d2 = 2a when I asked why it's 2a and then derived the ellipse equation which is not what I was looking for but the math was informative.

Comment: $2 a$ is just a constant.  Note that it is not identified as the major axis until the end.  I just call is as such to make life easier throughout the computation.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments we know that the sum of the distances from a point $(x,y)$ on the ellipse to the two foci is a constant. Now, that's true for any point on the ellipse, so look at a point on the ellipse on the line connecting the two foci. In this case, we're looking at a point $(a,0)$ defining the semi-major axis, and the distance is $(a-c) + (a-(-c)) = 2a$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can refer to the proof I've written:

Comment: It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.