# Find an equation for the ellipse with foci $(\pm 4,0)$ passing through $(-4,1.8)$

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Find an equation for the conic that satisfies the given conditions:

> Ellipse, Foci $(-4,0)$ and $(4,0)$, passes through $(-4,1.8)$.

I know how to do these questions with the vertices, but I'm kinda lost figuring this one out.

Comment: Let me know if you need any help after https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336622/analytic-geometry-high-school-why-is-the-sum-of-the-distances-from-any-point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $c = \sqrt{a^2-b^2}$. We know $c = 4$; so $16=a^2-b^2$ and $b^2+16=a^2$. 
Now you substitute in:
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

You obtain:
$$\frac{4^2}{b^2+16}+\frac{1.8^2}{b^2}=1$$

Solving for $b$, we find $b=3$ and $a=5$. The equation is: $$\frac{x^2}{25}+\frac{y^2}{9}=1$$

Comment: Thank you, this helped me understand how to solve these problems

Answer (score 0):

Hint: One way to define an ellipse is that the sum of the distances from a point on the ellipse to the two foci is the same for all points of the ellipse. Can you come up with an equation that expresses this fact?

Answer (score 0):

Matteo (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/686644/matteo), Find an equation for the ellipse with foci $(\pm 4,0)$ passing through $(-4,1.8)$, URL (version: 2019-07-23): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3301684